# Volume of region bounded by a Cylinder

Tags: integration, volume

I have the following problem:

Find the *volume* of the region bounded above by the cylinder 
$$ z=x^2$$
and below by the region enclosed by the parabola $$y=2-x^2$$ and the line $$y=x$$

I'm really struggling to visualize this region and come up with the limits of integration. I've made a couple of failed attempts at sketching the graph, none of which made any sense. I can't seem to find the correct region that satisfies the requirements. Can a kind soul help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. I guess you would like to evaluate the volume of the solid
$$S:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:0\leq z\leq x^2,x\leq y\leq 2-x^2,\;x\in[-2,1]\}.$$
Then
$$\mbox{Volume(S)}=\int_{x=-2}^{1}\int_{y=x}^{2-x^2}\int_{z=0}^{x^2}dzdydx.$$

Comment: It makes sense, but how did you get that $ x \in [-2,1] $ ?

Comment: @Marco Neves In the plane $z=0$, consider the intersection of the parabola $y=2-x^2$ and the line $y=x$.

Comment: @Marco Neves The final result should be 63/20. Any further doubt?

Comment: nope I got that as well. Thanks!